# How can I join two lists A and B, minimizing duplicates while preserving the relative order of each of the lists A and B within the resulting list?

Tags: python, list, dynamic, merge

I have two sequences of strings A and B input as lists which may or may not have contiguous duplicates.

```
A = ['S','D','D','M','C','M']
B = ['D','D','S','C','C','M']
```

I want to merge them while minimizing contiguous duplicates while maintaining the order of each sequence A and B.

```
R = ['D','S','D','S','D','C','D','M','C','M','C','M']
```

I want to find a dynamic programming approach to solve this problem but I am not sure where to begin or how to do it in python.

Comment: Can you provide your code attempt of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why does your `R` list start with `D`?  If you were making A + B I would expect the first (left-most) item to be `'S'`.  Please explain the algorithm you are using to produce the desired result.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh im not quite sure where to even begin to solve this problem. the question itself is from a dynamic programming chapter so i know i need to apply dynamic programming concepts but i just dont even know where to start to break this problem down

Comment: @cdarke R starts with D in order to minimize the repetition of D. If it had started with S then in order to maintain the order of the original sequences there would be a repetition of D

Comment: You seem to be using intuition for that sequence.  Please specify *exactly* the algorithm of how to decide where the duplicate should go and put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your merging us supposed to work. I tried

```
[k for k, v in itertools.groupby(heapq.merge(A, B))]
```

But that gives me:

```
['D', 'S', 'D', 'M', 'C', 'M', 'S', 'C', 'M']
```